# django collect static looking for nonexistent directory

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am getting an existing project running locally.  I am trying to collectstatic content to see my css, images, etc.

My project structure looks like:

myprojectname

--- myprojectname

--- --- myproectname

--- --- --- settings

--- --- --- --- base.py (setting.py)

--- --- static

--- --- --- image

Settings has the following static values set:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/myuser/myprojectname/myprojectname'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/Users/myuser/myprojectname/myprojectname/static',
)
```

I try to view an image in my template page like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static "image/logo.png" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

The image doesn't load.  When I see the path to the image, everything looks great and it is pointing to:  localhost/static/image/logo.png

When I try to collectstatic, I get the following error:

```
for entry in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myuser/myprojecname/myprojectname/myprojectname/static'
```

***Notice it is looking for 3 myprojectname directories.**

The problem is that I cannot see my static content like this image for example.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I notice that you use "myprojecname" and "myprojectname" interchangeably. Is this a typo?

Comment: It looks like it's looking for `/Users/myuser/myproject/myproject/myproject/static` and needs `/Users/myuser/myproject/myproject/static`. Notice 'myproject' appears thrice in the former and only twice in the latter.

Comment: i do see that, but why is looking 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some confusion here.
The STATICFILES_DIRS is list of directories that you collect from (as well as all other static folders in your apps)

the STATIC_ROOT is where to put the static file you are collecting.
So they cannot be both the same folder.

Comment: so what should I change them too? This has worked for me in several other projects.  Can you see when I collect static files it is looking through 3 directories of myprojectname ?